# Envio de formulário para banco de dados com Mysql e php

Tags: php, mysql

Alguém pode me ajudar a saber onde estou errando?! esta dando este erro nas linhas de identificação dos campos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Olá, porque você não tenta isso aqui:

```
<?php 

if ($_POST) {

 -- seu script --

}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Como seu POST ainda não foi inicializado(está vazio), aparece essa notificação. Para resolver você pode esconder o erro ou utilizar a condição is set

if(isset($variavel)){

// True se tiver conteúdo na variável e false se não tiver

}

Exemplo:

```
if(isset($_POST['nome')){
    $nome = $_POST['nome']
} else {
    $nome = NULL;
}
```

Se preferir pode inicializar as variáveis como por exemplo $nome = "";

Ou então desabilitar as mensagens de erro/aviso como já foi sugerido.

Comment: seria uma boa opção também colocar ele dentro do IF ?

Comment: Quando diz "ele" se refere a oque exatamente?

Answer (score 0):

As mensagens são notificações de que suas variáveis não foram declaradas anteriormente, isso não é um erro e sim notificação, você pode desabilitá-las definindo `display_errors` como `0` ou usar a função [error_reporting()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting).

Como fazê-lo.

```
<?php
// Adicionar no começo do seu código PHP.
error_reporting(0);
?>
```

Outras opções interessantes para essa função:

```
<?php

// Report simple running errors
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

// Reporting E_NOTICE can be good too (to report uninitialized
// variables or catch variable name misspellings ...)
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);

// Report all errors except E_NOTICE
// This is the default value set in php.ini
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
// For PHP < 5.3 use: E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE

// Report all PHP errors (see changelog)
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Report all PHP errors
error_reporting(-1);

// Same as error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

?>
```

Conteúdo extraído da uma resposta no SOen. [How do I turn off PHP Notices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867057/how-do-i-turn-off-php-notices)